# Line 1, Column 1: character "‍" not allowed in prolog

Tags: character

When I am going to validate my page using w3c validator, I am getting : **Line 1, Column 1: character "‍" not allowed in prolog** error.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Prolog

Comment: about your problem, inspect your page for a BOM

Answer (score 2):

There is a character, or data interpreted as a character, in the document before the doctype declaration. In the error message quoted, there is the character [U+200D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) ZERO WIDTH JOINER (ZWJ) between the quotation marks, so this seems to be the culprit. ZWJ is an invisible control character. There is no point in having it at the start of a file, as it is supposed to cause ligature or joining behavior for the characters (usually letters) around it. ZWJ is invalid at the start of a document by HTML rules.

You may need a good editor, like [BabelPad](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelPad.html), to detect and remove the ZWJ.

Comment: Starting with the second character I copied all the text, pasted it into a new empty file, added the first character manually, then replaced the old file with the new one.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I copied all my code into a new fresh file and used that file instead. It worked for me